# Do people who have no sons go to hell?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, manu-smriti

Is it true that people who have no sons go to hell no matter how good they were in their life.
Also if in someone's  lineage  no son is born , the ancestors also fall in hell ?

There is a story in Mahabharat about one Jaratkaru whose ancestors were getting tortured in hell because Jaratkaru had no sons .

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaratkaru